# Via reflexão em java, setar e pegar valores de variáveis herdadas

Tags: java, reflexão, exceção

Tenho a seguinte hierarquia de classes

```
(POSTRequestHTTP extends ReqeustHTTP) 
(RequestHTTP extends ComunicationObjectHTTP )
```

Supondo que cada objeto pode ter variáveis correspondente a um item de um cabeçalho, e tenho que setar seus valores passando uma String e recuperar seus valores, recebendo uma String em tempo de execução.

Para não ter que implementar em todos as Classes, implementei apensas na classe de maior nível hierárquico (ComunicatonObjectHTTP), Os seguintes métodos:

1º Método para buscar campo na classe atual e nas classes pai, por seu nome.

```
protected Field getHeaderField(String fieldName)
    {
        Class current = this.getClass();
        boolean keepSearch = true;
    while(keepSearch)
    {
        try{
            return current.getDeclaredField(fieldName);

        }catch(Exception ex){}
        if((current = current.getSuperclass())== null)
        {
            keepSearch = false;
        }
    }
    return null;

    }
```

2º Método  para gerar uma String contendo todos os valores dos campos separados por linhas.

```
public String generateHeaders()
{
    String returnValue = "";
    for(String name : constList.getConstValues())
    {
        try{
        Field field = this.getHeaderField(this.getFieldNameByHeader(name));
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value =  field.get(this);

            if(value != null)
            {
                String stringvalue = ""+value;
                if(stringvalue != "")
                {
                    returnValue = returnValue + value + lineSeparator;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);}
    }
    if(returnValue != "")
    {
        returnValue = returnValue.substring(0,returnValue.length()-   lineSeparator.length());
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

3º Receber uma String setar o valor de cada campo  por linha de uma String passada como parâmetro.

```
public void loadHeaders(String protocol)
{
    if(protocol != null)
    {
        if(protocol != "")
        {
            this.headers = protocol;
            String[] lines = protocol.split(lineSeparator);
            for(String line : lines)
            {
                if(line == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                String[] nameAndValue = line.split(nameAndValueSeparator);
                if(nameAndValue.length >= 2)
                {
                    try{
                        Field field = this.getHeaderField(this.getFieldNameByHeader(nameAndValue[0]));
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        field.set(this,nameAndValue[1]);
                    }catch(Exception ex){}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Porém testei e mesmo os nomes das variáveis passados como parâmetro estarem correto, ocorre uma exceção informando que estas não foram achadas.
Alguém poderia, por favor, dar uma dica sobre algum erro que eu esteja cometendo, ou indicar um tópico falando á respeito desse assunto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há partes do seu código, como os métodos `getFieldNameByHeader` e `getConstValues`, que podem ser a causa do problema.

Por outro lado, não vejo erros gritantes no código postado, a não ser algumas más práticas (`catch` sem tratamento, por exemplo).

## Teste

Fiz um teste reconstruindo algumas partes do código e asumindo alguns valores.

Criei as seguintes classes:

### ComunicationObjectHTTP

```java
public class ComunicationObjectHTTP {

    protected Field getHeaderField(String fieldName) {
    Class current = this.getClass();
    boolean keepSearch = true;
    while (keepSearch) {
        try {
        return current.getDeclaredField(fieldName);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        if ((current = current.getSuperclass()) == null) {
        keepSearch = false;
        }
    }
    return null;

    }

    private String lineSeparator = "\r\n";
    private String headers;
    private String nameAndValueSeparator = "=";

    public void loadHeaders(String protocol) {
    if (protocol != null) {
        if (protocol != "") {
        this.headers = protocol;
        String[] lines = protocol.split(lineSeparator);
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (line == null) {
            break;
            }
            String[] nameAndValue = line.split(nameAndValueSeparator);
            if (nameAndValue.length >= 2) {
            try {
                Field field = this.getHeaderField(nameAndValue[0]);
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(this, nameAndValue[1]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

### RequestHTTP

```java
public class RequestHTTP extends ComunicationObjectHTTP {

    private String campo1;

    public String getCampo1() {
    return campo1;
    }   

}
```

### POSTRequestHTTP

```java
public class POSTRequestHTTP extends RequestHTTP {

    private String campo2;

    public String getCampo2() {
    return campo2;
    }

}
```

Então executei com os seguintes comandos:

```java
POSTRequestHTTP p = new POSTRequestHTTP();
p.loadHeaders("campo1=valor1\r\ncampo2=valor2");
System.out.println(p.getCampo1());
System.out.println(p.getCampo2());
```

E o resultado foi o esperado:

> valor1
>   valor2

## Conclusão

O problema que está enfrentando deve se tratar de um equívoco quanto aos valores recebidos ou pode ser uma falha nos métodos ausentes na sua pergunta (dos quais mencionei dois no início da resposta.

Veja a pilha de erros ou execute o programa em modo debug para ver em qual linha ocorre a exceção e qual o valor que está "quebrando" sua implementação.

## Sugestões

Não usaria herança para herdar métodos utilitários. Já fiz isso muitas vezes e só complica as coisas. Se você criar uma classe auxiliar que recebe um POJO e uma String com os valores para fazer o processamento, não precisará fazer com que suas classes de atributos estendam nenhuma outra classe, deixando seu código menos acoplado.

Além disso, existem muitas APIs de reflexão por aí que facilitariam sua vida. Considere o [Apache Commons Beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.1/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html). Ele possui um método `populate()` que recebe um POJO é um mapa. Então, tudo o que você precisaria fazer é quebrar sua String do "protocolo" em nomes e valores, adicionar num mapa e passar para o método.

Veja um exemplo da própria documentação (link acima):

```java
HttpServletRequest request = ...;
MyBean bean = ...;
HashMap map = new HashMap();
Enumeration names = request.getParameterNames();
while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
  String name = (String) names.nextElement();
  map.put(name, request.getParameterValues(name));
}
BeanUtils.populate(bean, map);
```

Enfim, reinventar a roda é legal por questão de conhecimento, mas usar soluções robustas de bibliotecas bem testadas é bem melhor para evitar problemas em produção.

Comment: Oi obrigado pela ajuda ,então getConstValues retorna uma lista de nomes de items de cabeçalhos e o getFieldNameByHeader pega um nome de cabeçalho e transforma no nome de uma variavel da classe

Comment: @user5020 Tem que garantir que o nome é exatamente o mesmo dos atributos. Por exemplo, se houver um cabeçalho `nome`, o atributo da classe tem que ser algo como `private String nome`.

Comment: sim é bem isto mesmo , irei te mostrar alguns exemplos de busca, No RequestHTTP tem os seguintes campos ` protected String headerAccept;
 protected String headerAcceptCharset;
 protected String headerAcceptEncoding;
 protected String headerAcceptLanguage; ` e coloquei um print no nome do campo pesquisado a cada vez que ele realiza uma busca   `
headerAccept 
headerAcceptCharset 
headerAcceptEncoding 
headerAcceptEncoding 
headerAcceptEncoding 
headerAcceptEncoding 
headerAcceptLanguage 
`

Comment: cara descobri era o getFieldNameByHeader nele eu uso o metodo replace("-",""); e acabava ficando um espaço no final, ai eu acrescentei o método trim(); , obrigadão pelas dicas.